# Why does perl skip statments in favor of while loop

Tags: perl, scripting

My perl script seems to skip over the if statements and execute the while loop first. If I take the while loop out, I will get the expected behavior(print some text, and proceed). I don't have any perl experience, so I'm wondering if this is something that is internal to the language that I don't know about?

```
$choice = <STDIN>;
chomp($choice);

if($choice == 1)
{
    print 'snap.exe';
    @args = ('snap.exe');
}
elsif($choice == 2)
{
    print 'v2u.exe';
    @args = ('v2u.exe');
}
elsif($choice == 3)
{
    print 'ImageMagick';
    @args = ('import','-depth','8','-window');
}

while(1)
{
    #dostuff
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not the matter of buffering? What happens when you prepend the whole `if-elsif` branch with `$| = 1;`?

Comment: The output is being buffered: `print "snap.exe\n";` to force output

Comment: @raina77ow Sorry, but my perl knowledge is not that good yet to even begin to know what you're talking about :(

Comment: Why don't you print out `$choice` before the first if, to see if you have what you think you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You're suffering from buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html).

All you need to do is add `$| = 1` before your print statements to force perl to output immediately instead buffering and waiting for newlines.

From [perlvar $OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#HANDLE-%3eautoflush(-EXPR-)):

> - `HANDLE->autoflush( EXPR )`
> - `$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH`
> - `$|`
>
>   If set to nonzero, forces a flush right away and after every write or print on the currently selected output channel. Default is 0 (regardless of whether the channel is really buffered by the system or not; `$|` tells you only whether you've asked Perl explicitly to flush after each write). STDOUT will typically be line buffered if output is to the terminal and block buffered otherwise. Setting this variable is useful primarily when you are outputting to a pipe or socket, such as when you are running a Perl program under rsh and want to see the output as it's happening. This has no effect on input buffering. See [getc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getc.html) for that. See [select](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) on how to select the output channel. See also [IO::Handle](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html).
>
>   Mnemonic: when you want your pipes to be piping hot.